# Interactive plotting with R raster: values on mouseover

Tags: r, plot, mouseover, interactive, r-raster

I'd like to do a small program in R for interactive visualization and modification of some raster datasets, seen as colored images.
The user should open a file (from the terminal it's OK), plot it, select the points to edit with mouse clicks, and insert the new values.

So far I achieved that easily. I use the `plot()` function from the `raster` package to visualize the plot, then `click()` to select the points and edit their value via the terminal.

I'd like to add the ability to show the values on mouse over. I've searched for ways on how to do this, but this doesn't seem to be possible with the standard R packages. Is this correct?

In this case, I may be forced to use external packages, such as gGobi, iPlots, Shiny or Plotly. However, I'd greatly prefer to [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and use only "standard" graphics tools, such as the raster `plot()` function or maybe trellis graphics objects (e.g. from `rasterVis`).

I understand a Shiny app would probably be best, but it takes lots of time to learn and perfect.

Comment: Maybe this is useful for you http://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/#interaction

Comment: @OscarPerpiñán: thanks, but I already looked at the interaction capabilities of rasterVis (which is why I mentioned it in the question) and as far as I can see `identifyRaster()` does not have many additional features compared to `raster::click`, which I already use. In particular, there is no way to display data on mouse over, which is specifically what I'm trying to do. Please correct me if I'm wrong, I'd be very happy to use such a nice solution (I love `rasterVis` and use it often).

Comment: You are right. `identifyRaster` and `click` are more or less the same (for lattice and base graphics, respectively). As far as I know what you are trying is not possible with the graphical device produced by R. I am afraid you will need some javascript code.

Comment: @Oscar: I'm afraid of that too. If you happen to have any suggestion of which method (I guess some D3.js interface) would be best advisable, i.e. which one is the easiest to adapt to my necessities, they would be most welcome.

Comment: I have no information about a solution combining javascript with raster data. You may try the `gridSVG` package to build your own solution. Perhaps [these examples](http://oscarperpinan.github.io/spacetime-vis/spatial.html#sec-3) (with point data) are useful for you: . Besides, the [htmlwidgets package](http://www.htmlwidgets.org/index.html) creates R bindings to javascript libraries but, as far as I know, none of them work with raster data.

Comment: I see that the github version of the excellent `ggiraph` now contains a function `geom_sf_interactive`, which works with the `sf` package. If I understand your needs correctly, I think that this could work for you and give you interaction without Shiny.

Comment: @pObs thaks for the input! Things have moved very fast since I posted this question: we now have `sf`, `leaflet`, `mapview`, `mapedit` etc. I think the question is a bit outdated now. Anyway, I did not know `ggiraph` had implemented `sf` objects already, nice!

Comment: why not add your solution then to the list below?

Comment: @AdrianTompkins what I did back then was very similar to what @SeGa implemented, which additionally implied re-drawing the raster image multiple times (I think `sf` was not out yet). It was slow, and clumsy.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With `leaflet`, `mapview`, and `leafem` you can achieve something like this:

```
library(raster)
library(mapview)
library(leaflet)
library(leafem)

f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)

leaflet() %>% 
  addRasterImage(r, layerId = "values") %>% 
  addMouseCoordinates() %>%
  addImageQuery(r, type="mousemove", layerId = "values")
```

---

Putting that in a **shiny** app you get:

```
library(raster)
library(mapview)
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)

f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% 
      addRasterImage(r, layerId = "values") %>% 
      addMouseCoordinates() %>%
      addImageQuery(r, type="mousemove", layerId = "values")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

The following example illustrates the idea of converting the raster to Simple Features / Shapefiles. Its not realy useable for big Files, but the labels can be designed individually, the data is **editable** and can easily be shown in a Table.

```
library(raster)
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
library(sf)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

## DATA
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)
r1 = aggregate(r, 30)

sp = st_as_sf(rasterToPolygons(r1))
cn = st_coordinates(st_transform(st_centroid(sp),4326))
sp = st_transform(sp, 4326)
sp = cbind(sp, cn)
sp$id <- 1:nrow(sp)
colnames(sp)[1] <- "value"


## UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map"),
  uiOutput("newValueUI"),
  textInput("newVal", label = "Enter new value"),
  actionButton("enter", "Enter new value"),
  hr(),
  dataTableOutput("table")
)


## SERVER
server <- function(input, output){

  ## Reactive Shapefile
  sp_react <- reactiveValues(sp = sp)
  
  ## Leaflet Map
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    pal= colorNumeric(topo.colors(25), sp_react$sp$value)
    leaflet() %>% 
      addPolygons(data = sp_react$sp, label= paste(
        "Lng: ", as.character(round(sp_react$sp$X,4)),
        "Lat: ", as.character(round(sp_react$sp$Y,4)),
        "Val: ", as.character(round(sp_react$sp$value,4))),
        color = ~pal(sp_react$sp$value), 
        layerId = sp_react$sp$id
      )
  })
  
  ## Observe Map Clicks
  observeEvent(input$map_shape_click, {
    
    click_id = input$map_shape_click$id
    
    click_grid <- sp_react$sp[sp_react$sp$id == click_id,]

  })
  
  ## Observe Action Button
  observeEvent(input$enter, {
    click_id <- input$map_shape_click$id
    sp_react$sp[sp_react$sp$id == click_id,]$value <- as.numeric(input$newVal)
  })

  ## Data Table
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    sp_react$sp %>% st_set_geometry(NULL) %>% 
      dplyr::select(id,X,Y,value)
  })
  proxy = dataTableProxy('table')
  
  ## Table Proxy
  observeEvent(input$map_shape_click$id, {
    req(input$map_shape_click$id)
    proxy %>% selectRows(as.numeric(input$map_shape_click$id))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I know this does not exactly answer my question, but I'll accept this answer anyway. I believe that with today's R packages, one would really think of doing this in leaflet/shiny, not using base `raster` or similar.

Comment: I dont know if `addRasterImage` supports mouse-events, I didnt find anything in the manuals. So 1 idea would be to create a grid with the same resolution as the raster and do the mouse-events based on that shapefile. Either do everything with shapefiles only or get only the center points of the clicked grid and filter the raster for that cell to include the values/coordinates in the labels.

Comment: Yeah, I'd do that too. But it gets clumsy with large shapefiles.

Comment: I think `mapview::addImageQuery` does what you are looking for.

Comment: Indeed.. Thank you @TimSalabim. I hope you dont mind, that I included it in my answer.

Comment: Not at all! It makes the answer more relevant IMO

Comment: It does definitly! But editing the values would still not be possible with rasters or? I could think of some ways for shapefiles though

Comment: No editing is currently not possible. Though we are working on this in mapedit. Maybe we can also provide something for raster data. I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: I just changed the shapefile example. The grid cells can be edited now, but its not performant, as the whole shapefile is redrawn upon entering a new value.

Comment: Yes, that's very similar to what I did in the past. I re-drew the raster image multiple times, every time a value was edited. It was not pretty. Maybe using `sf` polygons a neater solution could be achieved. In general it is much nicer to use polygons, since you do not have to interpolate the raster.

Answer (score 2):

I give you a simple example of how to do it in R without external Java libraries, if you want Javan's features you can adapt it, but each java graphics library is different and I have never done anything similar.

```
set.seed(123)
mydata <- data.frame(x = runif(10), y = runif(10))

edit_plot <- function(data) {
  plot(data)

  sel <- locator(n = 1)
  if(is.null(sel)) return(TRUE)
  dd <- (data$x - sel$x)^2 + (data$y - sel$y)^2

  data[which.min(dd),] <- edit(data[which.min(dd),])
  r <- edit_plot(data)
  if(r) return(TRUE)
}
edit_plot(mydata)
```

To exit press Esc when locator is active.